# Granting private access to two classes without introducing dependency

Tags: c++, oop, templates

I have class, say `Rectangle` that has a private method `Rectangle::paint`. I want to let two other classes access this method, and only those two. So, I thought of this:

```
template <class T, class Q> 
class Rectangle {
    void paint();
    friend T;
    friend Q;
};
```

Problem is, when I want to instantiate a `Rectangle` object in `T`, it means `T`needs to know about `Q`, either by including a header or by using a forward declaration, both of which I would like to avoid. Also, the other way around regarding `Q` not knowing about `T`. Is there a way to do this?

Edit: To clarify a bit, I want to instantiate `Rectangle` in `Foo`, but have it mean `Rectangle<Foo, Bar>` so that Bar could access private members from elsewhere. I don't want `Foo` to know about `Bar` or vice versa.

Thanks

Comment: Why make `Rectangle` a template? Just make `T` and `Q` friends, then `T` and `Q` need not know anything about each other

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number. 
Yes. I want to instantiate such a rectangle in Foo, but have it mean Rectangle<Foo, Bar> so that Bar could access private members elsewhere.

Comment: why make it a template? remove the first line, then `Q` and `T` need not know about each other.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I used a template to parametrize over T and Q. Today, I need it to be Rectangle<Foo, Bar> but my manager also wants Rectangle<Foo1, Bar1>, Rectangle<Foo2, Bar2> etc.

Comment: This sounds like a design problem. What do `Q` and `T` need to do that depends on accessing private members of `Rectangle`?

Comment: if `Q` needs to access a private method of `Rectangle<Q,T>` then that already implies hat `Q` knows about `T`. `Q` cannot know about `T` without knowing about `T`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number. Not really. Rectangle<T,Q> is just a purposed solution. Could as well be just Rectangle. Basically, how do you let two classes access a private method of a third class with both classes knowing about each other given the following constraints:
1. The identity of both classes needs to be parametrized
2. Only those two classes are allowed access.

Comment: @PeteBecker certainly a design problem. Suppose Rectangle has private member called color and only T and Q are allowed to set it, yet many other classes are allowed to instantiate Rectangle. They don't mind knowing about T, but absolutely can't know about Q.

Comment: @user4581301. Point taken, edited to remove tag.

Comment: @YakovDan -- solving design problems by coding hacks just leaves traps for the future. Fix the design problem and the coding hacks aren't needed.

Comment: @PeteBecker I agree. Still, I want to avoid refactoring legacy code if some clean, best practice solution exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Rectangle` is a template and parametrized on `Q` and `T`, then `Q` and `T` are part of the type. You cannot use `Rectangle<Q,T>` without "knowing" about `Q` or `T`.

How about this:

```
template <size_t> struct rectangle;

template <size_t tag>
struct rectangle_modifier { 
    void paint(rectangle<tag>&);
};

template <size_t tag>
struct rectangle {
    friend rectangle_modifier<tag>;
    private:
    void paint() {}
};

template <size_t tag> 
void rectangle_modifier<tag>::paint(rectangle<tag>& r) {r.paint(); }


struct foo : rectangle_modifier<1> {};
struct bar : rectangle_modifier<1> {};



int main () {
    rectangle<1> r;
    foo{}.paint(r);
    bar{}.paint(r);
}
```

`foo` and `bar` need not know anything about each other. They both can `paint` a `rectangle<1>`. The `tag` is because you said you want to have different rectangles that each let two different classes access their `paint`.

Note that this is rather intrusive (`foo` and `bar` must inherit), not sure if this is a problem.

Its also not safe in the sense that anybody can write another class that inherits from `rectangle_modifier<1>` to access `rectangle<1>::paint`. However, thats not really what `private` is for. `private` is to restrict accidential access and to make clear that one should not access it. It is not to prevent by all means that it can be accessed. If someone wants to hack it, they will find a way.

Actually I would simply make `rectangle::paint` public and call it a day. Encapsulation is to make sure invariants don't break. Painting a rectangle that can be painted does not break an invariant.

Comment: It's a step in the right direction. What if I don't want foo or bar to inherit, but I want foo  to have rectangles as members? 

I admit that paint is a rather contrived example that does not convey my meaning too well. Suppose paint changes some critical variable and for ease of debug I want to tightly control which classes are allowed to change said variable? Making paint public is not the way to go.

Comment: @YakovDan `foo` can have a `rectangle` as member and still inherit from `rectangle_modifier`. But honstely I am still totally confused about the requirements or the actual aim of all this. If the rectangle is a member of `foo` then make it a private member, thats all what is needed to make sure only `foo` can call its `paint` method. I dont see the bigger picture. What is `rectangle` really? What is `paint` in your real code? Its an example for what? Design isnt created out of thin air, design must be designed around the real things, the actual requirements

Comment: @YakvDan If you dont want `foo` and `bar` to inherit from a base class then there are other solutions without inheritance, but I think you should first try to clarify the question. Try to focus more on what you need and why rather than talking about what you think could be a solution.  I am afraid when I come up with something without inheritance there will be something else you don't like about it.

Comment: I completely share your frustration. I also agree that design problems don't live in a vacuum. It is also entirely possible that I do not understand the problem completely. I'll accept this idea using inheritance because it is definitely one way to do this and I'll keep thinking whether I can actually use this idea and if not, exactly why not. Hopefully, it will clarify the issue for me as well.